# Dots in the middle of the row by CSS or JavaScript

Tags: css, layout

Could you please help me to achieve layout as in this example?

[image: Sample Image]

Sample items in this list loads dynamically into view and length can be various. And it seems like the count of dots should change according to this. I try to use `<table>` element but it only I can set is dotted border to bottom and this is not my case because I need it in the middle of the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the dots a vertically centered background for the TD. The content itself has a white background, so that the dots are hidden under the text.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/QkEzr/

Comment: +1 also better than my js solution. I think this is the way to go.

Comment: +1 That's the right way to do. But if you're using td, you might have a fixed sized dotted line. You don't get a varied width. DIV's might help here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you could do in a quick and easy way with just CSS. Just create three blocks(div's). And give a bottom border to the middle div. Then move it's position a bit higher(margin-top with a negative value). I guess that's what you needed.

If you're using table, then no problem. Just add another div inside the second column. And add the bottom border as I said above. And move the div upper. Simple.

Comment: +1 for being clever; this is better than the javascript solution I was working on.

Comment: It's always better to do it with HTML & CSS than using any script unless it becomes harder or complicated.

Comment: This solution might lead to cut off dots, if that's a concern for you at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a javascript solution. The idea is to set the font to monospace, and then place dots depending on the number of characters in a given row relative to the max number of characters in the samples column.

```
var samplePts = new Array( new Array("Sample",23), new Array("Longer Sample",9), new Array("Much Londer Sample",125) );

var maxSampleLen = 0;
for (var i=0; i<samplePts.length; i++){
    var currLen = samplePts[i][0].length;
    if (currLen > maxSampleLen){
    maxSampleLen = currLen;
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<samplePts.length; i++){
    var outputStr = "<div style='font-family: monospace;'>"+samplePts[i][0];
    for (var n=0; n<maxSampleLen-samplePts[i][0].length+5; n++){
    outputStr += "&#183;";
    }
    outputStr += samplePts[i][1]+"</div>";
    document.write(outputStr);
}
```